# ReflectionException Container.php on line 826

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have two classes in the services layer
CashTransactionServices.php

```
namespace App\Services\Cash;

use App\Models\Cash\CashTransaction;
use App\Models\Cash\CashBoxTransaction;
use DB;

class CashTransactionServices {

    protected $AccountingAPI;

    public function __construct(AccountingAPI $acc) {

        $this->AccountingAPI = $acc;

    }
```

CashBoxTransactionServices.php

```
namespace App\Services\Cash;

use App\Models\Cash\CashBoxTransaction;

class CashBoxTransactionServices extends CashTransactionServices {}
```

and in the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cash;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\Cash\CashBoxTransactionServices;

class CashBoxTransactionController extends Controller {

    //
    private $services;

    public function __construct(CashBoxTransactionServices $cash_box_transaction_services) {

        $this->services = $cash_box_transaction_services;
    }
```

I have this error

**ReflectionException: Class App\Services\Cash\CashBoxTransactionServices does not exist in file C:\xampp\htdocs\easyerp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 826**

I made sure of using the right namespaces and the right classes names!

PS: when I remove the inheretance from CashBoxTransactionServices class It works!

Comment: Can you show us the full `CashBoxTransactionServices` class as it is in your app?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `namespace` and `use` declarations in your code examples above?

Comment: Are you using a service provider to inject this service or just using type hinting to autowire (if that's what it's called in Laravel) the service? Because if it's the latter, `CashTransactionServices` needs a constructor argument and my understanding is that you need to create a service provider to allow you to call the service with an argument.

Comment: @DarraghEnright why do i need service provider here?!

Comment: Maybe you don't—I deal mostly with Symfony so I am not very au fait with Laravel's autowiring. That said, it should actually work, if my understanding is correct. I do have one question though—what is the namespace of `AccountingAPI`? Is it in namespace `App\Services\Cash` as well?

Comment: yes it's in App\Services\Cash